# Where do I retrieve items bought at the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

I bought an item on the auction house a while back.

Where do I get it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a "Completed Auctions" tab on the auction house menu. Clicking on items in the list will give you the option to send them to your stash. You can't send items to your stash if it is full, but they can remain in the auction house indefinitely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its a real money auction house item, it may have to be cleared(processed by Blizzard) before you will receive the item.  This often happens if the amount paid is more than 10$.  In that case, the item may not show up in your completed tab for up to 2-3 days.