# In Diablo 3, I buy stuff in the auction house but I don't know where to find it

Tags: diablo-iii

When I buy things in the Diablo 3 auction house, it says I completed the purchase (gold purchases, not cash) but when I go to my stash in game, it's not there. Or in my inventory. I only am using 1 hero right now also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I retrieve items bought at the Auction House?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67854/where-do-i-retrieve-items-bought-at-the-auction-house)

Answer (score 8):

You have to send items purchased from the auction house to your stash explicitly.  This extra step is so you can purchase things you don't actually have space in your stash for, it lets you queue up to 50 things in the auction house "outside" of the game.

You do so from the left side of the Completed tab.

[image]

Select the item purchased, then hit "Send To Stash".

Pictured here is sending gold from the sale of an item, but the same system applies to buying items.

It doesn't really make sense that you have to send *gold* to the stash IMO, but whatever.

Comment: Does the sent gold go to the stash or just into the gold pool for your characters?

Comment: @Coomie - they're one and the same, stash = "gold pool" from a seller's perspective.

Comment: I think Coomie is asking if the gold will become a 'gold item' in your stash or if it just adds to your gold pool. It goes straight to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Completed' tab in the Auction House and check the menu on the left-hand side. You can send items to stash from there (and gold from completed auctions, too!)